# Split at number-letter

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, string, python-re

I want to split 'E100N05' into ['E100', 'N05']
, so split after a number become the letter N, E, S or W. The number of digits after a letter can be different.

```
import re
re.split('[NSEW$*]', 'E100N05')
Out[8]: ['', '100', '05']

What I want : ['E100','N05']
```

Which pattern should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
>>> re.split('(?!^)(?=[NSEW$])', 'E100N05')
['E100', 'N05']
>>>
```

Answer (score 5):

How about we rephrase the problem, so instead of "splitting" we just find all letters+numbers tokens, so:

```py
import re

res = re.findall('[a-z]+\d+', 'E100N05', re.I)

print(res)
```

Output:

```py
['E100', 'N05']
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `re.findall()` like below:

```
import re
re.findall('[NSEW$*]\d+', 'E100N05')
# ['E100', 'N05']
```